# Redis Functionality

Tags: redis

I am trying to use redis for a simple process.
Process :-
Read value for a key and update it.
Example :- (a,1)
Read a value and update 1 to 2.
The problem here is that in multithreaded environment ,multiple thread (say 4) read at same time and then update it to 2, actually it should have been 4 .Is there a way where in I can impose locking in redis such that if one thread reads a value it imposes a lock so that other threads are kept in waiting state?

Answer (score 0):

Use `INCRBY` to do an atomic increment:

```
redis> SET mykey "10"
"OK"
redis> INCRBY mykey 5
(integer) 15
redis>
```

---

Or, if you need something more sophisticated, use an uninterruptible [MULTI](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) command.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need the lock. In multithreaded environment, suppose 4, they send
`read` and `update` commands to Redis not in right order.
may be:

1:read->2:read->1:update->2:update->3:read->3:update->4:read->4:update

you need combine 1:read and 1:update to an atomic operation, that is `Lua Script`.

you can write a Lua script for all operation and execute it whit `EVAL` command, the multithreaded commands will in right order.